# If "Back" link with document.referrer is empty go to certain URL

Tags: button, document, back, referrer

I am using this code for generating a "Go back" link in my website

```
<script>
document.write('<button onclick="location.href=\'' + document.referrer + '\';">Go back</button>');
</script>
```

But when the user lands directly on this page (foe example after google search), the "go back" button doesn't work.

How can I do it in such a cases to go to mypage.html?

Thank you

Comment: Every browser has such a button already … or a key combination, or a mouse gesture … why re-implement functionality that already exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can also check if the referrer is empty with an if statement like this:

```
if (document.referrer != ""){
document.write('<button onclick="location.href=\'' + document.referrer + '\';">Go back</button>');
}
else{
document.write('<button onclick="location.href=\'mypage.html\'">Go back</button>');
}
```

Then you go to mypage.html and that doesn't happen with `javascript:history.go(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript history API: `javascript:history.go(-1)`.